# isinstance() does not work inside a function?

Tags: python, isinstance

When I query isinstance() in the console it works **True** , but when I use it in a function it does not work **False** !?? Why does this happen ?

```
In [104]: type(ab)
Out[104]: isdp.iSDP

In [105]: isinstance(ab, iSDP)
Out[105]: True

In [106]: xbitx(ab)
type>  <class 'isdp.iSDP'> False

In [108]: xbitx??
Signature: xbitx(data)
Source:   
def xbitx(data): #extract bit indexes 
        print "type> ", type(data), isinstance(data, iSDP) 
        if isinstance(data, iSDP) : return data.bits
        return data
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Where is your `xbitx()` function located? Does it import `iSDP` from a different module?

Comment: yes ... i have 2 classes if it matters ... class iSDP(object): ...  class isdp(object): ...with staticmethods

Comment: Well, try renaming one, say `iSDP` to `iSDPX` (including the implementation of `xbitx()`) to see if the behaviour changes.